# Bower doesn't generate components.json file, throws an error

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, bower

Okay so my problem is related to the use of Yeoman, specifically Bower.

On both my person laptop (OSX SL) and my colleagues laptop (OSX ML) the Yeoman suite has installed perfectly and an AngularJS project can be scaffolded successfully, then previewed with grunt.

My other machine however (ML), can scaffol an angular project, but the components folder is never generated. Because of this...

```
grunt server
```

throws an exception, obviously because the AngularJS file doesn't exist.

I've had a look through the Bower repo's issues but can't find anything relating directly to this issue. Bower also throws the same exception (tmp.js:260) when trying to install any project.

[image: ss]

I've uninstalled / reinstalled to make sure I'm running the latest version (0.9.2), same for with the other applications and the Angular generator - it's all up to date (Also ensuring I installed with the global flag).

I compared my $PATH file with my collegues and it's identical so I've ruled that out.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? I'm stumped for anymore ways I can troubleshoot, so any ideas are appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git` needs to be available in your command-line (in your $PATH). Try running `git` in your command-line to make sure it works.